# Flutter: A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'. > Cannot run Project.afterEvaluate(Closure) when the project is already evaluated

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, video-player, flutter-video-player

I am trying to build a flutter app that uses many packages, these packages can sometime be a problem with the compileSdkversion so whenever I try and change it new errors come up.

Whenever I do

```
flutter build apk --release
```

Wanting to build my app, I keep getting this error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/Users/user/dev/project/android/build.gradle' line: 26

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
> Cannot run Project.afterEvaluate(Closure) when the project is already evaluated.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                            4.4s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
```

Here is my build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.0'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
    afterEvaluate { project ->
            android {
                compileSdkVersion 31
            }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And here is my app/build.gradle

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 31

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.user.project"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my gradle-wrapper.properties

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.2-all.zip
```

I am using MacOS Catalina version 10.15.7 and Android studio Dolphin 2021.3.1 Patch 1

I have tried changing the compileSdkversion to 33 but it gives me another error with my video_player_android package.
I have also tried changing the distributionUrl to 6.9.2 and the com.android.tools.build:gradle to 4.2.2 but then I get this error with video_player_android:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:lintVitalRelease'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':video_player_android:debugUnitTestRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform bcprov-jdk15on-1.68.jar (org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.68) to match attributes {artifactType=processed-jar, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for JetifyTransform: /Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/1.68/46a080368d38b428d237a59458f9bc915222894d/bcprov-jdk15on-1.68.jar.
         > Failed to transform '/Users/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/1.68/46a080368d38b428d237a59458f9bc915222894d/bcprov-jdk15on-1.68.jar' using Jetifier. Reason: IllegalArgumentException, message: Unsupported class file major version 59. (Run with --stacktrace for more details.)
           Suggestions:
            - Check out existing issues at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:460323&s=modified_time:desc, it's possible that this issue has already been filed there.
            - If this issue has not been filed, please report it at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=460323 (run with --stacktrace and provide a stack trace if possible).

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2m 3s
```

I have tried every possible combination but keep getting either the first error or the second error with video_player_android (degrading the package it won't work)

Please feel free to ask more details or try and change things. Thanks

Comment: did you try flutter clean before flutter build apk --release ?

Comment: yes everytime I make a change but it still doesn't fix it